# Update one-to-one relation in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Hello i got the following entity class Book:
$

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private BookProfile bookProfile;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST , orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Rating> ratings;
```

$

i try to add a Profile like this:

$

```
Book book = manager.find(Book.class, bId);
BookProfile bookProfile = new BookProfile();
manager.getTransaction().begin();
book.setBookProfile(bookProfile);
manager.merge(book);
manager.getTransaction().commit();
```

$

But nothing happens the profile in Book is still null. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `MERGE` to the cascade types for your `bookProfile` field.